# OS X 10.9.3 finder issues

Tags: macos, finder

Upgraded the OS on my Desktop PC. Fixed the issue with lost folders in finder and Email.

My question is there any way to get back the Today, yesterday and week folders in the finder slide bar. When working with a large number of folders it was a very quick way to mover around them.

Also the folder size resize slide bar is not appearing in the new folder anymore, which was place at the bottom right of my screen.

Now you have to go right click, select Show View option Slide the icon size tab to required size. Then right click again to select arrange by name to get them all to fit back into the screen size.

Just a painful process when jumping between folders and pics etc.

Answer (score 1):

The icon size slider is still there when Finder is set to show the status bar. You can do that in "View" -> "Show Status Bar".

[image: "View" -> "Show Status Bar"]

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple questions here:

- The Finder Folders view by date can be set in Arrange menu tab.

[image: folders]

To show those folders in the Finder side bar (create those Folders) then just drag them to the side bar in the location of your choice. To adjust size in the side bar go to system preferences General settings and change it there.

[image: side bar]

- To get the size slider go in to View tab in Finder and select show Status Bar.

Comment: I still have that slider for resizing icons on 10.9.3. It's on status bar (?) shortcut ⌘+/